# How to express array annotation argument in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, annotations, spring-annotations

When annotation has an array argument with basic type like String or Int it is straightforward how to use that:

```
public @interface MyAnnotation{
  String[] props();
}

@MyAnnotation(props = ["A", "B", "C"])
class Foo {}
```

Unfortunately that does not work for values that are annotations themselves.

An example is `org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySources`:

```
public @interface PropertySources {
  PropertySource[] value();
}

public @interface PropertySource { 
  String[] value();
}
```

In Java syntax usage is

```
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource({"A", "B", "C"}),
    @PropertySource({"D", "E", "F"}),
})
class Foo{}
```

But in Kotlin the code with similar approach does not compile

```
@PropertySources([
    @PropertySource(["A", "B", "C"]),
    @PropertySource(["D", "E", "F"]),
])
class Foo{}
```

How to express this annotation array nesting construction in Kotlin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `value =` and remove the `@` from the child annotation declaration:

```kotlin
@PropertySources(value = [
  PropertySource("a", "b"),
  PropertySource("d", "e"),
])
class Foo
```

Also note that `@PropertySource` is `@Repeatable` so you can do:

```kotlin
@PropertySource("a", "b")
@PropertySource("d", "e")
class Foo
```

Comment: The trick is in the "value =". Ok, great. Are you sure the second code block compiles?

Comment: Yes, note i used latest kotlin (1.6.10)